# Matrices with entries from $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be the set of all $\ 2\times 2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b,c,d$ are integers modulo $2$, such that $ad-bc\neq 0$. Using matrix multiplication as the operation in $G$, prove that $G$ is a group of order $6$.

**Proof:** We know that $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{[0],[1]\}$ where $[0], \ [1]$ are equivalence classes.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
c_1 & d_1
\end{pmatrix}\in G$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}
a_2 & b_2 \\
c_2 & d_2
\end{pmatrix}\in G$ then $$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1a_2+b_1c_2 & a_1b_2+b_1d_2 \\
a_2c_1+d_1c_2 & b_2c_1+d_1d_2
\end{pmatrix}$$ since $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ then entries of $AB$ also belong to $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Also $\text{det}(AB)=\text{det}(A)\text{det}(B)\neq 0$ Right?
So matrix multiplication is binary operation. Associativity holds for any matrices and it is true also in this case. The identity matrix $E\in G$

But when i was checking inverse matrix I stucked. If $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 \\
c_1 & d_1
\end{pmatrix}\in G$ then $$A^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{pmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{pmatrix}$$
Why this matrix lies in $G$? The first entry is $\dfrac{d}{ad-bc}$ and it need to be an integers.

Can anyone please explain this moment to me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are told that $a,b,c$ and $d$ are integers modulo $2$. What does that mean? It means that they're not elements of $\Bbb Z$, but of the group (actually a field) $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z=\{[0],[1]\}$ (also called $\Bbb Z_2$ for short). The operation $+$ in that group is defined by $[0]+[0]=[1]+[1]=[0]$ and $[0]+[1]=[1]+[0]=[1]$.

Thus, when we compute $ad-bc$, we obtain, not an ordinary integer, but either $[0]$ or $[1]$. Since we're excluding the case $ad-bc=[0]$, then we have $ad-bc=[1]$.

Now, we ask, what is meant by $\frac{1}{ad-bc}$? If this expression is to be meaningful, its value must be the unique solution to the equation $(ad-bc)x=[1]$; i.e., we're looking for a multiplicative inverse. Since we have $[1]\cdot[1]=[1]$, we can "divide", and obtain $\frac{[1]}{[1]}=[1]$. A less confusing notation might be: $[1]^{-1}=[1]$.

The omission of brackets is common, and unfortunately confusing. :/

This interpretation is necessary in order for the problem to make sense. If we allowed for a matrix whose determinant is $2$ (ignoring for the moment that $2$ is not, itself, an element of $\Bbb Z_2$), then we would not end up with a group at all.

Comment: It says that $ad-bc\neq 0$ but i guess it does not mean that $ad-bc\notin [0]$. In $\mathbb{Z}_2$ we can have $ad-bc=2\neq 0$ but $ad-bc\in [0]$. It's my opinion.

Comment: Since we're dealing with integers modulo $2$, the idea is that $ad-bc\ne [0]$. If we allow determinants that are $0\pmod 2$, then we haven't got a group. We're trying to write down invertible matrices. Remember $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are themselves equivalence classes; that's what integers modulo $2$ *are*. The result of the operations $ad-bc$ is therefore another equivalence class.

Comment: 1) How did you conclude that $a,b,c,d$ are equivalence classes? There is nothing about in Herstein's book (this problem is from that book). 2) You again wrote $ad-bc\neq [0]$. Could you explain in detail, please? Your answer is too brief.

Comment: In $\Bbb Z_2$, there is no element called "$2$". There is only $[1]$ and $[0]$.

Comment: +1 Your edited is much better and I've understood most unclear moments. But could you expand and clarify the last paragraph of your edited answer?

Comment: Indeed we have that $ad-bc=[1]$ but why $1/(ad-bc)=[1]$? Intuitively i understand that it's but cannot prove it rigorously. As you said above $ad-bc$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, namely $[1]$. How you divide the number $1$ into the element $[1]$? For now it's quite pointless

Comment: Great question. I'll edit.

Comment: Sorry for such annoying questions :) because right now i am interested in abstract algebra and i would like to know these questions in depth

Comment: The last question: We know that $ad-bc$ is an element from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ but why the author writes $ad-bc\neq 0$? It's quite meaningless

Comment: They just omitted the brackets. Once we have established our context, that is a common abuse of notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for brilliant answer!

Answer (score 1):

If $ad-bc\ne0$ in $\mathbf F_2$, then necessarily $ad-bc=1$. Furthermore, we have a group because $G$ is actually  defined by the condition $\det A=1$, and the determinant is multiplicative (over any field), i.e. $\det (AB)=\det A\cdot\det B$.

Comment: We are dealing in $\mathbb{Z_2}$ and we have condition $ad-bc\neq 0$ but as i said above it does not mean that $ad-bc\notin [0]$ because for example $ad-bc=2\neq 0$ but $2\in [0]$. Hope that you understood my question. This moment is really unclear for me

Comment: @RFZ: You seem to misunderstand the nature of $\mathbf Z_2=\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$, which is usually  denoted $\mathbf F_2$ when seen as ‘the’ field with two elements. Its elements are not integers, but congruence classes modulo $2$. There are only two congruence classes: even numbers ($\leftrightarrow 0$) and   ($\leftrightarrow 1$)  In this field `2=0=4,&c.`

Comment: Your answer really helped. Indeed, I had misunderstanding about the structure $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But what about inverse matrix in the set $G$?

Comment: The inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ has determinant  the inverse of $\dat A=1$ so it's $1$ too. The formula for the inverse is the same in all fields : it is $\dfrac1{\det A}\operatorname{adj}A$. As  here the determinant is $1$, the inverse is just the adjugate of $A$. Is it what you wanted to know?

Comment: Not quite! I do not know fields but i hope that i will learn them soon. We know that the elements of matrix $A$ are from $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{[0],[1]\}$. And it's determinant is $ad-bc$ is also from $\mathbb{Z}_2$. And we know that the inverse of $A$ is equal to another matrix with factor $1/(ad-bc)$ since $ad-bc$ is an element from $\mathbb{Z}_2$ how to define $1/[1]$ and what does it mean? Intuitively i know that it is $[1]$ but i am not able to prove that rigorously.

Comment: Well the inverse of $1$ is $1$, whatever the field, since $1\cdot 1=1$. Incidentally a field is just a structure  with two operations like addition and multiplication, and the same properties as in $\mathbf Z$ – this is called a commutative ring – plus the existence of multiplicative inverses for all non-zero elements. So it's like $\mathbf{Q,~R,~C}$.